# How can I fetch comments of Instagram posts using API?

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

I have a sandbox API account and I am not able to fetch Instagram posts comments data. I try to use

```
$comments = $instagram->getMediaComments($media_id);
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 400
            [error_type] => OAuthAccessTokenException
            [error_message] => The access_token provided is invalid.
        )

)
```

---

**Update**: Key and secret are correct because all other info I am getting, like comments count, is correct.

Now I have changed

```
return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id . '/comments', true);
```

and added scope

```
private $_scopes = array('basic', 'likes', 'comments',
    'relationships', 'public_content', 'follower_list');
```

now the authentication error is gone but the comment data is still blank.

Comment: According to your error I would make sure your key and secret are correct; seems your not obtaining authorization to make your call properly (the user has either not granted your app permissions or your app's key and secret are incorrect); I'd check these settings first

Comment: key and secret are correct because i am getting all others info like comments count are correct. now i have changed 

return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id . '/comments', true);

and added scope 
private $_scopes = array('basic', 'likes', 'comments', 'relationships', 'public_content', 'follower_list');
now authentication error are gone but comment data still blank